# Get the ListView's width in the Array Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which will be either full screen width (phone) or roughly 1/3 of the width if it's a landscape tablet. In the List it will display an imaged on a remote server.

Obviously the image can take some time to download the image, so, in the JSON data, I have an average colour of the image as hex, and the ratio of the image. What I want is, in the adapter, to fill the image with the average colour at the right size. I've got the colour part down, using this code

```
final ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(blog.getAverageColor()));
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(blog.getFullPath()).placeholder(cd).into(img);
```

However, I can't get the size to work. My original idea was to call **getWidth()** on the view, and times it by **blog.getRatio()**, then set the images height to that, and it's width to the width of the view.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(r, parent, false);
    }

    if (view == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int width = view.getWidth();
```

However, width is always 0. How can I get the width of the view? Or is this just not possible to do like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get width of listView by call `parent.getWidth()`.  `parent` is a view that your view will be attached to. So your view will have same sizes.

`view.getWidth()` returns 0 because at this point your view isn't really added to ListView.

Comment: This will return 0 the first time (i.e. if it's not yet drawn), and I'm not sure how to bypass that without forcefully updating the adapter a second time or something like that. I feel like this is a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @aviator This question was about `ListView`. I'm not sure if using `ListView` in 2018 is a good idea. Maybe RecyclerView would be a more convenient way to show list in your app?